# ElasticBeanStalk NGinx configuration for multiple ports in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-load-balancer

I have my nodejs hosted in ElastiCbean stalk environment.
It uses the default configurations and default port.
Now I am planning to open another port and listen to that port from Nodejs applicaiton. This is kind of opening nodejs in mutliple ports.

I have done the nodejs coding part.But i am not sure of the nginx changes to make it to listen to multiple ports.
Can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 0):

I've only configured nginx for [Java backends](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-nginx.html), but essentially you will need to configure the `server` directive to include the additional port you want to listen on, such as:

```
server {
  # listen for the extra the port the load balancer is forwarding to
  listen        88;
  access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

  client_header_timeout 60;
  client_body_timeout   60;
  keepalive_timeout     60;
  gzip                  off;
  gzip_comp_level       4;

  location / {
    # forward to the actual port the application runs on
    proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8888;
    proxy_http_version  1.1;

    proxy_set_header    Connection          $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

So I recommend ssh on to your Nodejs EB server and fish around for your nginx config directories, looking for `nginx`, `conf.d` folders, or 
 an `nginx.conf` file. When you find it, [you can override the default `server` config, or apply an `include` statement to extend it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-nginx.html), either way the `server` directive above should allow access on multiple ports as far as nginx is concerned.

Comment: it doesn't have the `includes` like the Java env, you have to use a custom configuration: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-platform-proxy.html

Comment: Thanks, I generalized my answer a bit